# Images not loading on Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, image, web, safari

A lot of images from [this website](https://spred.com.br) that I developed are not being loaded when using **Safari on iOS**. Safari on MacOS loads it normally, as well as Chrome, Edge and Firefox in mobile or PC.

The main issue is related to the images in the Clients slider, that for some reason fail completely to be displayed.

1. I am not using .WEBP images
2. There is no HTTPS mixed content
3. Caching and lazy loading were disabled
4. The website is developed using WordPress and PHP
5. The images in question can be loaded directly (if accessed by their URL)

I don't have an iPhone, but my client does (that is how we found the problem out), so the only way I am being able to test the changes I am making is by using an online emulator.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to view your site on Safari macOS as well as iOS. The client slider remains empty. Having a look at your source shows that your images are referencing a URL, which Safari might be blocking due to its privacy controls. Perhaps reference these images locally in the application?

Try to restructure your slider to something simpler such as a grid of containers to see if that resolves it. Something about your HTML formatting is not playing well with Safari, I would suggest following HTML5 style guidelines and debugging your application for any errors in loading assets or networking / browser compatibility.